# Compiling a groovy template to a class file i tomcats work dir

Tags: tomcat, groovy, gsp

I just installed tomcat (6.0.20) with groovy-all.jar (1.7.2) in my WEB-INF/lib

My web.xml file looks like this

```
<web-app>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Groovlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Template</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>groovy.servlet.TemplateServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Groovlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.groovy</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Template</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When i run an ordinary jsp file, it constructs a java file in my tomcat work dir and compiles it to class.

fx. test.jsp becomes test_jsp.java and test_jsp.class.

When i run a groovelet or a groovy template, it does not create any files in work.

Are the result compiled to another folder, or is it compiled every single request?
If so, is there a way to configure groovy to compile classes to work?

Answer (score 0):

GroovyServlet compiles the groovy files into objects of type java.lang.Class and than caches those class objects in memory.

if you want to precompile them to class files, I guess you have to use groovyc is stated in http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Precompiling-groovlets-td935580.html